# Arithmetic relation between expectation values of transformed random variables

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be discrete non-negative random variables with $E(X_1) \le E(X_2)$. Assume a function $f$ with the following properties:

- $f$ is positive, i.e. $f(x) \ge 0$
- $f$ is (strictly) monotone increasing
- $f$ is concave

I conjecture that $E(f(X_1)) \le E(f(X_2))$ but couldn't find an appropriate reference. Could you provide a reference for a proof of this (or a more general property implying this case) and/or sketch the basic proof idea?

Remark: The concrete case for which I require this property is for random variables $X_1,X_2$ that evaluate to $[0,1]$ and $f(x) = 1-(1-x)^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}, n \ge 1$.

Comment: Have you considered applying  _[Jensen's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)?_

Comment: @Dilip Jensen's Inequality applies to convex, not concave, functions.

Comment: @whuber As Wikipedia's web page on Jensen's Inequality states, "In its simplest form the inequality states that the convex transformation of a mean is less than or equal to the mean after convex transformation; it is a simple corollary that the opposite is true of concave transformations."  So as soon as one sees expectations of convex **or concave** functions being considered, it should be second nature to check whether Jensen's Inequality can be used on the problem.

Comment: @Dilip I agree: but a quick check confirms it does not apply here.

Comment: @whuber I would have said that Jensen's Inequality can be applied to $E[f(X_i)]$ but does not help in proving the inequality conjectured by the OP -- which is just as well because, as your own answer shows, the conjectured inequality is not true in general.

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$\Pr(X_1 = 1/2) = 1,\ \Pr(X_2 = 1) = p,\ \Pr(X_2 = 0) = 1-p.$$

These random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ are manifestly discrete and non-negative. From

$$\mathbb{E}[X_1] = 1/2,\ \mathbb{E}[X_2] = p$$

it follows that $\mathbb{E}[X_1] \le \mathbb{E}[X_2]$ whenever $1/2\le p\le 1$.

When $f(x) = 1 - (1-x)^n$ for some specific $n\ge 1$ (which indeed is a concave function), note that $f(0) = 0,$ $f(1/2) = 1 - 2^{-n},$ and $f(1) = 1.$

If $n \gt -\log_2(1-p),$ which is finite and greater than or equal to $1$ provided $1/2\le p \lt 1,$  then

$$\mathbb{E}[f(X_1)] = (1)f(1/2) = 1 - 2^{-n} > p = (1-p)f(0) + (p)f(1) = \mathbb{E}[f(X_2)],$$

reversing the inequality and **contradicting the conjecture.**

---

More generally, for any such $f$ the conditions imply $f(1/2)\gt (f(0) + f(1))/2$, from which it follows there is an interval of values of $p$ in $(1/2, 1/2+\varepsilon),$ $\varepsilon\gt 0,$ for which the conjecture is false.